# Asp.net set conditional from url string

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am new to asp.net and I need a little help.

The problem
I need to set the visibility of a button based on whether or not "newflag" appears in the url. For example http://localhost:38805/result.asp?newflag

I have to use asp.net and javascript

Here is my current asp.net and JS code

asp.net

```
newflag = Request.Form("newflag")

    If newflag = false Then
        newflag = "null"
        Else
        newflag = "true"
        End If
```

JS

```
var newflags = '<%= newflag %>';
        console.log(newflags);
        if (newflags === "null" ) {
            document.getElementById('newflag').style.visibility = "hidden";

        }
else if(newflags === "true" ){

    document.getElementById('newflag').style.visibility = "visable";
}
```

Currently I am getting false from the console even with adding it to the url string.

Comment: Does the ASP.NET code need to know if that value exists in the URL parameters?  You can check the URL parameters through javascript without ASP.NET code

Comment: I do not think that javascript has a way to handle that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks! that worked! if you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of leveraging ASP.NET to get the query string parameter and set it to a variable to be later read by Javascript, why not just use Javascript?

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) answer for a detailed list of how to read query string parameters in pure Javascript